# What does the "2" indicate in 2:4 format for Excellon drill files?

Tags: gerber

For Excellon drill files, I know that the number after the colon indicates the precision, i.e.

- 2:3 has 1 mil resolution
- 2:4 has 0.1 mil resolution
- 2:5 has 0.01 mil resolution

However, I don't know what the number **before** the colon indicates.  What does the "2" mean?

Comment: It doesn't support boards more than 99 inches long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number before the colon designates the whole number digits, while the number after the colon indicates the number of precision digits.

For example, the number "37.294" would be represented in the following way:

- 3:4 - 037.2940
- 2:4 - 37.2940
- 2:3 - 37.294

Answer (score 1):

The "2" in your examples represents the number of digits the are represented to the left of the decimal point.

Most often the drill data file will be padded with leading zeros on the left side to fill out the number of specified digits.